# Haskell Binary Tree Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am a beginner in haskell and I need to display the value in a tree based on directions specified in a List (Path). I have liste below the Data structures , I want to understand why my recursive feature that i have implemented is wrong

```
import Data.List

 data Step = L | R
 deriving(Eq,Show)

type Path = [Step]  

 data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
             | End
        deriving (Eq,Show)

      leaf :: a -> Tree a
      leaf x = Node x End End

     ex :: Tree Int


     ex = Node 4 (Node 3 (leaf 2) End)
               (Node 7 (Node 5 End (leaf 6))
                     (leaf 8))



        valueAt :: Path -> Tree a -> Maybe a
        valueAt (p:ps) (Node a l r)  
                               | p == L = valueAt ps l 
                               | p == R = valueAt ps r
                               | ps == [] = Just           
                               | otherwise = Nothing
```

// When i execute this it says non exhaustive function at valueAt. So im guessing my recursive idea was implemented wrong. Can anyone explain why .

Comment: Indent your code properly! `valueAt` as it is, continues the previous line `... 8))`!

Comment: Do not use `==` here. It has its uses, but it does not belong in this code at all. Use pattern matching here instead of guards.

Answer (score 1):

You did not handle the case `valueAt [] someTree`. The line `valueAt (p:ps) ...` only matches a *non empty* list starting with `p` and continuing with `ps`. `ps` might be empty, but `p:ps` never is.

If you compile with the flag `-Wall`, GHC should warn about this at compile time. I would strongly recommend this.

As a style suggestion, avoid guards such as `p == ...` since they do not perform any pattern match. Try instead something like

```
valueAt :: Path -> Tree a -> Maybe a
valueAt []     (Node a _ _) = Just a    -- note the "a" !
valueAt (L:ps) (Node _ l _) = valueAt ps l
valueAt (R:ps) (Node _ _ r) = valueAt ps r
valueAt _      End          = Nothing   -- in all the other cases
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern match for `valueAt` does not cover `[]`, because `(p:ps)` will fail on an empty list. However, it is not necessary that it do so. Guards are evaluated in the order they are written, which means that your `p == L` and `p == R` guards are evaluated *before* your `ps == []` case. In other words, you have put your edge case after your recursion cases, resulting in an invalid pattern match. This code should fix that.

```
valueAt (p:ps) (Node a l r)  
                           | ps == [] = Just    
                           | p == L = valueAt ps l 
                           | p == R = valueAt ps r       
                           | otherwise = Nothing
```

However, your code has another problem. The function has the type description `valueAt :: Path -> Tree a -> Maybe a`, but in your edge case (`ps == []`), `Just` has type `a -> Maybe a`; `Just` is applied to *too few arguments*. Try this instead.

```
                           | ps == [] = Just a
```

Now that your errors are fixed, I would also suggest moving from guards and `==` to pattern matches. It will be simpler, faster, and less error prone.

```
valueAt :: Path -> Tree a -> Maybe a
valueAt []     (Node a _ _) = Just a
valueAt (L:ps) (Node _ l _) = valueAt ps l
valueAt (R:ps) (Node _ _ r) = valueAt ps r
valueAt _      _            = Nothing
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot , this has helped a lot , yea the guards kinda make it look more complicated. thank you for spending your time on this.